# drupal: how to post a comment through services API?

Tags: web-services, drupal, rest, mobile

I am currently developping a mobile application with a drupal 7 website as a backend. Using the services API with a REST server I was able to easily access the nodes, users, files and comments to see their content. 
I am able via a POST request to log in the website but I cannot create a comment through the services API. Actually, there is no error and a new comment is well created in the database but it is empty and its nid is 0. 
I also tried to download a valid comment, modify it with new datas, and send it but I have the same result.
I also need to add that the comments I am using or not just simple ones, they include some specific fields in their form.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem ? Has anyone ever experience something similar ?
Thank you

Comment: Related question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/22277/10645

Answer (score 0):

Check you are posting an object that is correctly structured, services isn't doing a comment_save()

Have a look at the test scripts for the structure

http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/tests/functional/ServicesResourceCommentTests.test#l100